# Can MYSQL Create table if exists return 0 or 1 Python

Tags: python, mysql

I use Python to read whether my MySQL database contains a specific table.

I currently have this code:

```
cur.execute("SHOW TABLES LIKE hello123")
table_found = cur.fetchone()
if table_found: # if table is found immediately start cupdate current operation
    do_task()
else:
    sql_create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hello123 (Serial VARCHAR(30), Quantity INT(11),ID INT(11) NULL, Status VARCHAR(30))"
    cur.execute(sql_create)
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(file_name,header=0,sep=",")
        for col in data.itertuples():
            cur = conn.cursor()
            sql_insert = "INSERT INTO hello123 (Serial,Quantity,ID,Status) VALUES(%s, %s,%s,%s)"
            cur.execute(sql_insert, (col[1],col[2],col[3],"IDLE"))
        do_task()
        return
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("file is not found in CSV file")
        return
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to simplify this further and instead of checking whether the table exists with "SHOW TABLES LIKE hello123" , do everything with a single mysql query `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

My idea is:

```
sql_create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hello123 (Serial VARCHAR(30), Quantity INT(11),ID INT(11) NULL, Status VARCHAR(30))"
cur.execute(sql_create)
query_result = cur.fetchone()
if(query_result == FALSE):
# dont need to create table, do task immediately
do_task()
else:
# table created, insert values into table and do task
   try:
        data = pd.read_csv(file_name,header=0,sep=",")
        for col in data.itertuples():
           cur = conn.cursor()
           sql_insert = "INSERT INTO hello123 (Serial,Quantity,ID,Status) VALUES(%s, %s,%s,%s)"
           cur.execute(sql_insert, (col[1],col[2],col[3],"IDLE"))
   do_task()
```

Can someone clarify whether something like this is possible with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` query?

Comment: Is the *real* question how to only insert data into a new table? Or empty table? Because `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` already does what it says. It doesn't need `SHOW`

Comment: You could use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert only non-duplicate rows. You could check the `COUNT(*)` of the table after creation and only insert rows if the table is empty.

Comment: Do not forget to take into account that the table may exist but its structure may differ - you'll find that the table exists but the insertion will fail.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hello. When I use SHOW table, when the table is found, I immediately start task, however, if I do not use show table and just use create table if not exists, if the table already exists, is still going to instert duplicate data which I want to avoid. My main goal is to reduce the number of queries and make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: I have tried INSERT IGNORE method as you have suggested, however, I do not think it is going to work in my case. The table contents may change, however, if the table exists, I still do not want to insert anything as long as there is something there. INSERT IGNORE will only work if the contents did not change